# Reading data from a hive table into a dask dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, hive, dask

I want to read the data from a hive table which has about 110mm rows and just 2 columns into a dask dataframe. Has anybody done this ? I'm using a pyhs2 connection to hive.

Currently i am reading the data into a pandas dataframe by limiting the number of rows.

**Current code --**

```
import pyhs2
import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as dd

conn = pyhs2.connect(host='10.xx.xxx.131', port= 10000, authMechanism='PLAIN', user='userid', password = "passWoRD",database='default')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("select * from hive_table limit 100000")
res = cur.getSchema()
description = list(col['columnName'] for col in res)  ## for getting the column names of the table 


headers = [x.split(".")[1] for x in description]

df= pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(),columns = headers)  ## code for getting data into pandas dataframe

# df.head(n=20)
```

How can I do something like this ? Any help would be appreciated.

```
df= dd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(),columns = headers)
```

Comment: Hive points to concrete files on HDFS.  It might be more efficient to query this data directly using functions like `dd.read_csv` or `dd.read_parquet` rather than go through hive itself.  However, we should probably make a convenient way to query the Hive metastore to find those files for you automatically. (this does not exist as of February, 2017).

Comment: @MRocklin , I agree with you.  reading the data into dask dataframes for just 1mm rows takes about 3 min, 29 seconds using the pandas df route ```df= pd.DataFrame(cur.fetchall(),columns = headers)   %time ddf  =   dd.from_pandas( df , npartitions = 1000)```   I'll attempt doing it through dd.read_parquet

Comment: @MRocklin, I have doing it using dd.read_csv. Steps are as follows: First write the hive table to local directory using the following:  `insert overwrite
    local directory '/path/extract'
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    STORED AS TEXTFILE select * from hive_table;`  It spits out 18 files in the following format:   000000_0.crc ....... 000000_8.crc  and 000000_0 ......... 000000_8 , with the later files being the data files. Then  I'm reading it using :  `ddf = dd.read_csv('\\path\\extract\\* ' ) ;` in python.

Comment: The problem is it doesn't read the header and is short by 9 rows from the original table. My guess its concatenating the 9 data files ( 000000_0 etc.) and treats the first row of each chunked csv file as the header and combines them into a dask dataframe. Any ideas on how to circumvent this problem ?  Btw the entire process is very fast in about 10-15 seconds compared to lets say reading 1mm rows in 3 min, 29 seconds.

Comment: Perhaps screw around with the keyword arguments like `header=False`?  Pandas/Dask.dataframe provide several options here.